# Неправильный вывод чисел

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, вывод

с помощью js нужно найти все натуральные числа из промежутка от 1 до 200, у которых количество делителей равно N, N вводим сами

В моем коде, получается, мы добавляем к счетчику +1, когда находим его делитель и должно выводиться по итогу само число, у которого N делителей, но у меня выводится почему-то только число 200... В чем может быть проблема?

```
function vtoroe()
{   
    var countt;
    var temp;
    var N = document.getElementById("N").value; //считывание N
    for (var i = 1; i<=200; i++) 
    {   
        temp=0;
        countt = 0; 
        for (var j = 1; j<=200; j++) 
        {
            if (i%j == 0 ) //проверка на делимость числа без остатка
            {
                countt++;
            } 
            if (countt == N)
            {   
                temp=i;
                document.getElementById('otvet2').value=temp+', '; //вывод числа, если его счетчик равен N
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вынесите проверку  if (countt == N) за цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваша проблема в том, что вы недосчитываете делители до конца и уже делаете какие-то выводы, т.е. у числа может быть больше N делителей, но вы уже на N делителях начинаете что-то считать

вместо

```
    for (var j = 1; j<=200; j++) 
    {
        if (i%j == 0 ) //проверка на делимость числа без остатка
        {
            countt++;
        } 
        if (countt == N)
        {   
            temp=i;
            document.getElementById('otvet2').value=temp+', '; //вывод числа, если его счетчик равен N
        }
     }
```

надо бы

```
    for (var j = 1; j<=200; j++) 
    {
        if (i%j == 0 ) //проверка на делимость числа без остатка
        {
            countt++;
        }
    }

    if (countt == N)
    {   
        temp=i;
        document.getElementById('otvet2').value=temp+', '; //вывод числа, если его счетчик равен N
    }
```

кроме того, почему бы вам сначала не найти все делители и занести их в массив, а уже потом вывести в том или ином виде

```
let arr = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 200; j ++)
{
    for (let j = 1; j<=200; j++) 
    {
        if (i % j == 0 ) //проверка на делимость числа без остатка
        {
            countt++;
        }
    }

    if (countt == N)
    {   
        arr.push(i);
    }
}

const str = arr.join(', ');
document.querySelector('#otvet2').value = str;
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы оказались правы! Теперь код работает верно

Comment: а в массив у меня не получалось добавлять)) совсем забыла про метод push...Спасибо за альтернативный способ)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('otvet2').value = document.getElementById('otvet2').value + temp + ', ';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! 
Оказывается, и в выводе была допущена ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

```js
let count = 0;

for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 200; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
}

console.log('count: ', count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('otvet2').value=temp+', ';
```

К примеру здесь правильные ответы это `50`, `100` и `200` и происходит следующие

```
temp = 50
value = temp + ", " = "50, " 

temp = 100
value = temp + ", " = "100, "

temp = 200
value = temp = ", " = "200, "
```

то есть у вас `value` не дополняется а полностью заменяется